# An interesting task in OOP which I don't get

Tags: java, oop, object

It is a task preparing to an exam for Java beginners. It makes me sick

Could somebody explain me why it is so?
Could someone correct me please :)
I tried to do step by step all methods and for me is so:

1)  Baumhaus b = bauHaus(2, 3);

It means that:

```
b.hohe = 2
b.breite = 3
```

2)  Baumhaus c = machBreiter(b);

```
c.hohe = 2
c.breite = 4
```

3)  c.nachbar = b;

```
c.nachbar.hohe = 2
c.nachbar.breite = 3
```

4) Baumhaus d = machHoeher(b);

```
d.hohe = 3
d.breite = 3
```

5)  d.nachbar = b;

```
d.n.h = 3
d.n.b = 3
```

6)  ++c.hoehe;

```
c.h = 3
c.b = 4
```

7)  Baumhaus e = machHoeher(b);

```
e.h = 3
e.b = 3
```

8)  e.nachbar = c;

```
e.n.h =3
e.n.b =4
```

9)  e.breite = b.breite - 1;

```
e.b = 2
```

10) c.hoehe++;

```
c.h = 4
c.b = 4
```

11) c.breite -= 2;

```
c.b = 2
```

**Could someone explain me why at the end of program b.hohe = 4** ?? For me it was 2

```
public class Hausbauer {
    static Baumhaus bauHaus(int hoehe, int breite){
        Baumhaus b = new Baumhaus();
        b.hoehe = hoehe;
        b.breite = breite;
        return b;
}

    static Baumhaus machBreiter(Baumhaus b){
        Baumhaus bb = new Baumhaus();
        bb.hoehe = b.hoehe;
        bb.breite = b.breite + 1;
        return bb;
}

    static Baumhaus machHoeher(Baumhaus b){
        b.hoehe++;
        return b;
}

public static void main(String[] args){


    Baumhaus b = bauHaus(2, 3);
    Baumhaus c = machBreiter(b);
    c.nachbar = b;


    Baumhaus d = machHoeher(b);
    d.nachbar = b;
    ++c.hoehe;
    Baumhaus e = machHoeher(b);
    e.nachbar = c;
    e.breite = b.breite - 1;
    c.hoehe++;
    c.breite -= 2;
    boolean bUndCBenachbart = (b.nachbar == c || c.nachbar == b);

    //QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS
    System.out.println(bUndCBenachbart);
    System.out.println(b.breite  );
    System.out.println(b.hoehe  );
    System.out.println(c.breite  );
    System.out.println(c.hoehe  );
    System.out.println(d.breite  );
    System.out.println(d.hoehe  );
    System.out.println(e.breite  );
    System.out.println(d.hoehe  );
    System.out.println(Baumhaus.naechsteNummer  );

}
}

class Baumhaus{
    public int hoehe;
    public int breite;
    public Baumhaus nachbar;
    public int nummer = ++naechsteNummer;
    static int naechsteNummer = 0;
}
```

Comment: A Java exam with class and variable names in German? Doesn't look like a *good* exam to start with.

Comment: `machBreiter(Baumhaus b)`  should probably return _the same_ instance that is passed as a parameter rather than a new one - much like `machHoeher(Baumhaus b)`.

Comment: @Mena it makes me shudder as well but some professors/teachers in Germany create such a code (as well as `gibHoehe()` instead of `getHeight()` )

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger and you will see what each line of code does and where this value is changed.

Comment: If `machBreiter()` and `machHoeher()` should return the same instance then `c.nachbar = b;` in your main method would mean that `b` is it's own neighbor and every operation on `c` would be reflected on `b` (they both reference the same object). So either that code is wrong or the methods would have to _both_ return a new instance.

Comment: What you are doing is using functions on Objects. And in an unintuitive way - why does macBreiter create a new, broader, house instead of making the original house broader.

Comment: debugger is your friend.

Comment: It is an exam task :( I don't know what that should check :/

Answer (score 0):

You should use methods instead of functions, that also makes the code more understandable. (Besides, as Mena has mentioned, german names in english code are strange)

```
House house=new House(2,4);
house.broaden(2);
house.lengthen(4);
```

Usually, static in beginner code is a sign you did something wrong.

Comment: It is prepared task... So I haven't written it. So I don't understand why after executing code there is b.hohe = 4. So your answer is not on my question :P

Comment: In that case, the answer from Peter Lawrey is the most useful :-). - Honestly, that's the easiest way to understand what happens...